# Wildcard mask 'or' operator is not working

Tags: vba, ms-word, find

In MS Word's find and replace the wildcard 'or' Operator is not working.

What is the '**or**' operator and how to use it with wildcards in a find and replace macro?

I want to find the word `English` written with various capitalizations, for example:  EnGlish,enGLish.

So I want to use OR operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word's Find functionality does not have an OR operator, but for this particular requirement you can use the following Find term: [eE]nGlish

If you want to replace it with English, then type exactly that in the Replace box.

Test that it works. Then record a macro when executing the action. That will give you the basic code you need. You can use it "as is" if that's all you need, otherwise you can modify it to perform additional actions.